# Volume of a parabolic solid

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals, solid-geometry

We intend to find the volume of a solid described as follows:

The $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ axes are such that the base of the solid is in the $XY$-plane and the vertical direction is parallel to the $Z$-axis. The base of the solid is the region in the $XY$-plane bounded by $y^2$ $=$ $1-x$ and the $Y$-axis. Each cross-section of the solid perpendicular to the $X$-axis is a square.

What would the be the definite integral to calculate the volume of this solid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis start at  $x=0$ and end at $x=1$. Let $A(x)$ denote the area of the cross section perpendicular to the $x$-axis that intersects the $x$-axis at $x$.  The solid can be thought of as the "sum of the cross sections" as they range from $x=0$ to $x=1$.   The volume of the solid is thus
$$\int_{0}^1 A(x)\,dx.$$

We need to find an explicit expression for $A(x)$ in terms of $x$. We know that the cross-section at $x$ is a square. The bottom vertices of this square are  bounded by the parabola $x=1-y^2$. So, the side length $\color{maroon}{\ell_x}$ of the square is $\color{maroon}{\ell_x}=2\sqrt{1-x}$; and thus, $$A(x)=(\,2\sqrt{1-x}\,)^2.$$  So the volume is
$$\int_{0}^1 (\,2\sqrt{1-x}\,)^2 \,dx  = \int_{0}^1 4(1-x) \,dx  .$$

---

In the diagram below, we are staring down the $z$-axis.  The base of the solid is enclosed by the green curve.  A cross section at $\color{maroon} x$ would appear as the line segment $\color{maroon}{\ell_x}$. This cross section is a square with side length $\color{maroon}{\ell_x}=2\color{maroon}{\sqrt{1-x}}$.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake. I meant $y^2$ $=$ $1-x$ and not $y$ $=$ $1-x^2$.
I've edited the question now.

Comment: @SidharthIyer I updated my answer.